# How to get method name of called webservice.asmx on the server side

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx

Im calling some of my WebMethod from my Web service on the client side. It's .NET webservice.asmx. Then When i process this request on the server side first its going to AuthModule : IHttpModule. There i need information about method name.

I need to get information about the name of called webservice method on the server side.

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;`

returns `.../serviceName` but i need to recognize which method was called. Any idea?

Comment: without method name how are you calling web method?

Comment: im calling method of this web service on the client side. And then When i process this request on the server side first its goint to AuthModule : IHttpModule. There i need information about method name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SOAP, try this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["SoapAction"]
```